# Force downloading a file using Spring MVC and a self-implemented interceptor produces a weird issue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, httpresponse, interceptor, force-download

All of my controllers extend the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractController {

    public HttpServletRequest request;
    public HttpServletResponse response;
    public ModelMap model;

}
```

Moreover, I implemented the following interceptor:

```
public class HttpRequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws ServletException {
        if (handler instanceof AbstractController) {
            AbstractController controller = (AbstractController) handler;
            controller.request = request;
            controller.response = response;
            controller.model = new ModelMap();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        if (handler instanceof AbstractController && modelAndView != null) {
            AbstractController controller = (AbstractController) handler;
            modelAndView.addAllObjects(controller.model);
        }
    }

    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
    }

}
```

This is a solution I found to improve the factorization of my code, since you won't need to pass the `request`, the `response` and the `model` as method parameters within your controllers. The solution works fine, until I found this issue:

```
public class HomeController extends AbstractController {

    @RequestMapping
    public void download1() {
        // use the parent attribute response
        File file = new File(MY_FILE_PATH);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        response.flushBuffer();
    }

    @RequestMapping
    public void download2(HttpServletResponse response) {
        // use the response passed as parameter
        File file = new File(MY_FILE_PATH);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        response.flushBuffer();
    }

}
```

Both of the two methods above make the browser downloading a file, but the `download1` one generated an empty file while the `download2` generates the original file as it should. Any idea why?

Thanks to the debugger, I noticed that in the `postHandle` method of the interceptor, the `download2` method generates a `modelAndView` which equals `null`, while the `download1` one generated an instanciated one. This should mean something for the issue, but I can't find what.

How get a `response` instanciated when passed as a parameter of a controller's method?

Comment: Do you define your controllers in `prototype` scope? Otherwise you should not store any conversational state in their fields, beacuse the same instance of your controller is shared among all requests.

Comment: I've never heard about a `prototype` scope... What do you mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8887831/106261

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do this :

```
public abstract class AbstractController {

    public HttpServletRequest request;
    public HttpServletResponse response;
    public ModelMap model;

}
```

Instance variables in controllers (which have default scope of singleton btw) is a bad idea.

Comment: you are sharing instance variables, that are not managed by spring, between requests. A controller is accessed concurrently by multiple requests, so should be thread safe. Having instance variables borks this.

Answer (score 3):

Just make something like this (to a txt file):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/download", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String download(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/force-download");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("/folder/file.extension");
    return IOUtils.toString(fr); // IOUtils come from Apache Commons IO
}
```

Comment: I had problems in my tests because the Jackson `ObjectMapper` was trying to serialize the file. I solved the issue adding the produces attribute to `@RequestMapping` as showed here.